# shutdown without password using doas

Tags: linux, permissions, doas

I want to be able to shutdown (or restart) my system without having to enter my password. My `/etc/doas.conf` looks like this and my user is in the `wheel` group

```
permit nopass :wheel as root cmd /sbin/poweroff
permit nopass :wheel as root cmd /sbin/reboot

permit :wheel
```

I thought this would be enough so I can enter

```
$ poweroff
```

but I get the message

> poweroff: must be superuser.

when I do

```
$ doas poweroff
```

I still have to enter my password.

How can I configure doas so that my user can `poweroff` or `reboot` without having to enter my password? And is it possible to configure it so that I don't have to enter `doas` at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commands that you enter in the `doas.conf` file (which you *should* enter with a full path for safety) has to occur exactly like that on the command line.  This means that to power off your system, you would type

```
doas /sbin/poweroff
```

You may obviously set up a handy alias for this:

```
alias poweroff='doas /sbin/poweroff'
```

With that alias in effect, you would just have to use `poweroff` to power off your system.

Additionally, the last match in the `doas.conf` file counts. In your case, the `permit :wheel` matches due to you being in the `wheel` group, and this does not specify `nopass`, which means that you will have to use your password with `doas` to run `/sbin/poweroff`.

Simply delete that last rule in the `doas.conf` file (or move it to the top):

```
permit        :wheel
permit nopass :wheel as root cmd /sbin/poweroff
permit nopass :wheel as root cmd /sbin/reboot
```